# Passing a function object as function argument

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to simply pass my initialized function object to my own function in several ways.

I did not find any examples with own functions just with "for_each" but as far as i understand it should work the same way.

```
void    f(int& n, void (*g)(int& m) ){ g(n);};

class TEST{
public:
    int init=0;
    TEST(int _init):init(_init){}
    void    operator() (int& m) {m+=init;}

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int k, m;
    cin >> k >> m;

    TEST    mytest(m); // OK, creates object with initialization
    mytest(m);         // OK, using initialized object's "operator()"

    f(k,mytest);       //  error: cannot convert 'TEST' to
                       //  'void (*)(int&)' for argument '2'to
                       //  'void f(int&, void (*)(int&))'

    f(k,TEST(m));      //  error: cannot convert 'TEST' to
                       //  'void (*)(int&)' for argument '2'to
                       //  'void f(int&, void (*)(int&))'

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `template <typename F> void f(int& n, F g){ g(n);};`

Comment: ... because a function object is a broader term, and is not in general convertible to a *function pointer*.

Comment: mytest is not an int, have you tried &mytest().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's common between a function pointer of type `void (*)(int& m)` and an instance of `TEST`?

They are callable with an argument of type `int&`.

What's the difference?

They are two different types. Unless you use a function template, they cannot be used interchangeably.

Hence, the solution for you is to use a function template.

```
template <typename Callable>
void f(int& n, Callable c )
{
   c(n);
}
```